# Blind source separation using FastICA

Tags: python, unsupervised-learning, independent-component-analysis

Reading [the example by scikit-learn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/decomposition/plot_ica_blind_source_separation.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-decomposition-plot-ica-blind-source-separation-py) on how to use the FastICA function, I couldn't understand the following plot:

[image]

In the third plot ("ICA recovered signal") - why is the magnitude different than the true sources' magnitude (second plot).
I there a way to obtain the estimated sources' real variance?